# Why subprocess.call () is showing error in linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

Let us consider Linux platform where I need to execute a program called smart.exe which uses input.dat file. Both the files are placed in the same directory with each file having the same file permission 777.

Now if I run the following command in the terminal window smart.exe is fully executed without any error.

```
$./smart.exe input.dat
```

On the other hand, if I use the following python script called my_script.py placed in the same directory, then I get an error.

my_script.py has the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, subprocess

exit_code = subprocess.call("./smart.exe input.dat", shell = False)
```

The error is as follows:

```
File "my_script.py", line 4, in <module>
exit_code = subprocess.call("./smart.exe input.dat", shell = False) 
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call

p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can someone please tell me why this is happening. Please note that the smart.exe should take around 10 sec to fully complete. This may be a clue for the problem.

Please also advise if there is any other way to run smart.exe from my_script.py. Your solution is much appreciated!

Comment: How do you intent to run a windows binary file on a Linux machine? Are you using something like WINE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decide if you want shell support or not.

If you want the shell to be used (which is not necessary here), you should use `exit_code = subprocess.call("./smart.exe input.dat", shell=True)`. Then the shell interprets your command line.

If you don't want it (as you don't need it and want to avoid unnecessary complexity), you should do `exit_code = subprocess.call(["./smart.exe", "input.dat"], shell=False)`.

(And there is no point naming your binarys `.exe` under Linux.)